# Unit Testing authenticated user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I am developing an app and now I need to do some testing. Everything in the app is based on authenticated user so this is the first test that I need to do. I have a google captcha in the form but I modified the `.env` file so that will not be required. This is my feature test.

```
public function test_users_can_authenticate()
{
     $user = User::factory()->create();

     $response = $this->get('/login', [
         '_token' => csrf_token(),
         'email' => $user->email,
         'password' => 'secret',
         'g-recaptcha-response' => ''
     ]);
        
     $this->assertAuthenticated();
     $response->assertRedirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

The test is failing  on this line `$this->assertAuthenticated();` saying that `The user is not authenticated. Failed asserting that false is true.` I did not now what can I do to make it work. I tried `php artisan config:clear` before `php artisan test`, not working. I uncomment the lines in `phpunit.xml`

```
<!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/> -->
<!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
```

but still with no result. Working with Laravel 8.x. What can I do to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use `sqlite` instead of `mysql` in your `phpunit.xml`:

`<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>`

Also share your routes file but i think the call should be a `post` and not a `get`

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? That said, there seems to be a lot of magic going on, starting with the `User::factory()`, which is as bad as a global variable. Generally, using dependency injection would be preferred, IMHO.

Comment: @rachids neither `post` or `get` is not working for the route. And with the `sqlite` connection from `phpunit.xml` it's throwing me the error `could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)`.
And the routes for the login are the ones from `make:auth`.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is for you to create a protected function in your `TestCase.php` like this.

```
protected function user()
{
    return (User::factory()->create());
}
```

After you do this, you can call it in the test of your application.

```
public function test_users_can_authenticate()
{
$this->actingAs($this->user()
->assertStatus(302);
}
```